# Client print sensor data

Tags: html, web, arduino, server

I am trying to enter a sensor value inside a number box

```
 client.println("<p><form><input type=number value=Currenttemp readonly>");
```

Currenttemp is and integer for my sensor temp but when i upload the code the box is blank. Anyone have any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
client.println("<p><form><input type=number value=" + String(Currenttemp) + " readonly>");
```

Be sure that CurrentTemp is not empty.